Extend parent view slot in RouterLink vỉew
I have a defined Vue route, parent view, and two child views
./route/index.ts

const router = createRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/dataset/:dataset_name',
            component: DatasetItemView,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: DatasetOverview
                },
                {
                    path: '/dataset/:dataset_name/downloads',
                    component: DownloadView
                }
            ],
        },
    ]
})

./views/DatasetItemView.vue
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ten columns">
            <div>
                <RouterLink :to="`/dataset/${route.params.dataset_name}`">Overview</RouterLink>
                <RouterLink :to="`/dataset/${route.params.dataset_name}/downloads`">Downloads</RouterLink>
            </div>

            <RouterView />
        </div>

        <div class="submenu two columns">
            <li>
                <RouterLink to="/">Back</RouterLink>
            </li>
            <!-- <slot></slot> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

./views/DatasetOverview.vue
<template>
    <p>Dataset overview</p>
</template>

./views/DownloadView.vue
<template>
    <p>Download view</p>

    <-- Want to extend here -->
</template>

I want to reuse <div class="submenu">...</div> in child views and extend the div to add more <li> in ./views/DownloadView.vue.
Is there any way to archive that as I checked <RouterView /> only adds slot at <RouterView /> position or my design is wrong?
Solution
thanks @alexander-nenashev I'm able to solve my problem with
/route/index.ts
{
    path: '/dataset/:dataset_name',
    name: 'dataset',
    component: DatasetItemView,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            name: 'dataset_overview',
            components: {
                default: DatasetOverview,
                submenu: DatasetItemMenu,
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dataset/:dataset_name/downloads',
            name: 'dataset_downloads',
            components: {
                default: DownloadView,
                submenu: DownloadMenu,
            }
        }
    ],
}

./DatasetItemMenu.vue
<template>
    <h6 class="grid-heading">Quick Actions</h6>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <RouterLink to="/">Back to home</RouterLink>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Addition actions -->
    <slot></slot>
</template>

./DownloadMenu.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import DatasetItemMenu from './DatasetItemMenu.vue'
</script>

<template>
    <DatasetItemMenu>
        <p>Additional actions here</p>
    </DatasetItemMenu>
</template>


You could bother with named views:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html
Or just use a teleport:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<template>
    <p>Download view</p>
    <teleport to=".submenu">
        <li><a>Downloads submenu</a></li>
    </teleport>
</template>

